# gnome keyboard layout setting only having effect in certain apps

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm on Fedora 25, Gnome shell version 3.22.3. I have changed keyboard layout via GUI `Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources` and adding (and selecting) English (Dvorak) variant.

The weird thing is that the dvorak layout do have effect in gnome-terminal, nautilus etc., but not in many other applications, like gvim, chrome.

Why is it only partially applied? How to apply the new layout globally?

---

Edit: In "partially applied" Dvorak mode, Gnome keyboard shortcuts are still in their QWERTY positions, e.g., "Super+D" to show desktop.

Comment: First guess is that it's a Gnome setting via some input method that's only used by Gnome applications. Does the output of `xmodmap -pke` reflect the Dvorak assignments?

Comment: @dirkt No, `xmodmap -pke` didn't show any difference when toggling between QWERTY and Dvorak. By the way, `localectl` output didn't change either (shouldn't `X11 variant` show up?)

Comment: So for X global settings, why not try with `setxkmap` (and convert to `xorg.conf` config) like e.g. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/toggle-between-dvorak-and-qwerty) in the answer with  `grp:alt_shift_toggle`? (If you don't want to toggle, you can simplify it, of course). I've no idea how this interacts with the Gnome settings, though, you may have to expirement.